# Should I use <html>, <head> and <body> tag?

Tags: html

I tried CodeAvengers.com and it's really nice. They say this:

> Most HTML code contains 3 tags that we have not used yet: `html`, `head` and `body`. These tags are optional; since Google recommends not using optional tags, we don't use them.

Why does Google recommend not using them? I think that `html` tag is useless, but `head` and `body` don't look useless. I think that these two tags make sense.

Can someone explain to me why Google doesn't recommend them? And another thing is that Google doesn't recommend them, but Google uses them. So?

Comment: Where does google recommend not to use them? It'd be nice if there was some reference as I can see in the code of google.com a <html>, <head> and <body> tag.

Comment: Do you have any reference?

Comment: Well the only reference I found is this http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml?showone=Optional_Tags#Optional_Tags and CodeAvengers - HTML level 1 - Lesson 9.3

Comment: @MíraKapičiak 's link target states that "For file size optimization and scannability purposes, consider omitting optional tags." In other words, omit the tags if you want to save a few bytes.

Comment: Well you should work to meet the standards of the W3C, not google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reference I can find is talking about [reducing HTML document file size](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-html).  Other than that it doesn't seem like Google doesn't *recommend* them, it's just saying that it's valid to exclude them and you can reduce file size and speed up your site.  However, I doubt that it will have any effect on you personally.

I think it comes down to personal preference.  For example the supposed duplicate answer suggests that omitting the tags makes test cases more focused/clear.

I'm personally used to using these tags for production because it removes all ambiguity for what you intend.  You may also want to add attributes to the `<html>` (such as `lang`), `<head>`, and `<body>` tags that would not otherwise be added automatically.

If you really crave for your HTML to be as small as possible when it's served while at the same time keeping your code clear for developers, I'm sure you can find a preprocessor that will remove unnecessary HTML tags and more for you.